# Identify a plant found in a Cairns planter box

Tags: identification

The following plant was in a planter box at a hotel in Cairns - it was about 30-40cm in width and spread across the ground without rising more than 15cm or so in height.  Had no fragrance or other defining characteristics beyond those pictured at the time photographed (winter).  It's been deliberately planted rather than self seeded.

[image: Unidentified plant]
[image: Close up of Unidentified plant]

I've tried running it through Pl@ntNet Identify, which has suggested with roughly 30% confidence it's Beyeria or a myrtle, though it seems quite small for that.

Would be grateful for any help in identifying it.

Comment: That’s tropical Australia.